# Batch Increment File Name from Remote Folder

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-rename

I want to Rename a .TXT file with the date & auto increment number in a windows batch, or powershell script.
 I.E. 20121004ABC.txt, 20121004ABC_02.txt, 20121004ABC_03.txt. . .

The tricky part is these files get moved to a different folder when they are uploaded. I want the incrementing number to continue if files are in the archive folder with the same date...

SO 20121004ABC.txt, 20121004ABC_02.txt, 20121004ABC_03.txt are uploaded and moved to C:\return\archive
Later that day 4 new .txt files are put in c:\return, i would like to run a batch file to name them
20121004ABC_04.txt, 20121004ABC_05.txt, 20121004ABC_06.txt, 20121004ABC_07.txt

The next day the incrementing number will restart, 20121005ABC.txt, 20121004ABC_02.txt
So far i have :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET date=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
ren %%a %date%_0!count!.txt
set /a count+=1
)
```

But this is obviously just a start and doesnt answer a lot of my issues!

-will not continue incrementing number from archive folder
-I believe there are some unknown issues of the loop function and writing over other files etc!

Comment: Where does the `ABC` part of the name come from?

Answer (score 0):

AS i mentioned i am new to coding and learning a lot. I have come up with a technique to solve my problem that is probably messy, but seems to do the trick! I would like to share incase anyone else has similar problem. Also if anyone has any critique to do on this code, PLEASE do i will take it as constructive critisisim and gladly imporve the code on my side.

Also just as another point that may or may not be helpful, I use a SQL query to Export a txt file and then use Cygwin

Thanks!

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash C:\s3\return\split.sh 'Shell Script to Split DB Export file into 25000 line Pieces
CD C:\s3\return\Returned_ARCHIVED 'Directory of Archive of Files To continue Counting from
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a 'Newest File in Archive Directory
Set Name=%newest:~0,8% 'Take only the important part of the File name
Set /a FileNum=%newest:~12,2% 'Take only the incremental number part off the filename
SET date=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
If %date% == %Name% (set /a count=%filenum%+1) Else (set /a count=0) 

'if the latest file in the archive is from today date +1 ifnot Start at 0

cd C:\s3\return 'Directory if Files that need renamed
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od ABC_*') do (
ren %%a %date%ABC_0!count!.txt
set /a count+=1
)
```

PS : Please Give me some reputation so i can give others credit for the help they provided me!

Thanks!